# Is there any problem if I chown my /usr/lib/node_modules will there be any security or package problems?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was wondering if I chown **/usr/lib/node_modules** to **myusername:myusergroup**, are there any problems I will encounter on my modules or is it okay for development purposes?

I find the permission denied error whenever I try installing a global package.

**Error**

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
```

Comment: I’d instead install `nvm` which avoids all of this and not muck with system directories and permissions.

Comment: This is the best way, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 ways to solve your problem:

1) Giving access permission to the current User:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/
```

In Your Case

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/lib/node_modules/
```

2) use `sudo` to install it as the root user.

3) Follow the npm guide mentioned below to change the settings to resolve any EACCESS errors - [NPM GUIDE TO FIX EACCESS ERRORS](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

Comment: Thanks @Lone wolf, I followed the guide and used nvm, it works fine. That is solution 3

Answer (score 1):

Try: 
add `sudo` before your command with npm

Comment: I am trying to avoid entering the root password, every time I want to install a global package